# JQuery: Convert array into function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function defined like this:

```
doSomething(a,b,c){// ...}
```

And an array defined like this:

```
var args = [$(‘.p’),‘#ffc’,’10px’];
```

I want to call doSomething and pass it all the elements of args as parameters.

Something like:

```
doSomething($(‘.p’), ‘#ffc’, ‘10px’);
```

Note that I dont want to change doSomething to have an array as arguments.

Any help !

Comment: Use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (like `doSomething.apply(null, args)`) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (like `doSomething(...args)`)

Comment: Sorry ! But i dont undestand what you mean

Comment: MSCom, there are two ways to do exactly what you want, using javascript.  @ibrahimmahrir has provided you with those two methods with links to more details.

Comment: Ok. I get the point now. I have seen the links. Thanks guys